Flutter How to manage , a text and listview together?
I'm building a chat in flutter, using a list of messagemodel(List messages) to update the view of the chat screen.
MessageModel{
String? content;
bool? isUser;
}

The View is generating. but the main issue im facing is that the response from server is a stream and i'm using stringbuffer to  catch all the stream values and pass that to the list.
so on chat view the response is follows
hello server

hi
hi,
hi, how 
hi, how are
hi, how are you     // the list duplicates itself on the view.
hi, how are you?

but when i add that to the text, every character is updating as expected, but the view can't be maintained. because the messages has only user messages. So for the solution im trying to show the text when buffer sends data and append it to the list, when the stream ends. how can i do that?
ie piece up a listview and a text together?
hello server // from list
hi, how are you? // from server.

and the list is autoscrolling. Anyone has a better idea than this? a best approach?!!
